# Mostrar datos con ListView con Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Estoy usando Django 1.8 con Python 3.4, necesito mostrar los datos de una tabla con `ListView` pero no me muestra nada ni me muestra algún error.

Aquí les dejo el código:

**models.py**

```
class Tipo_almacen(models.Model):
      descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=50)

      class Meta:
         db_table = 'Tipo_almacen'
         verbose_name_plural = "Tipo de Almacenes"
         verbose_name = "Tipo de Almacen"

      def __str__(self):
          return self.descripcion
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from mantenimiento.forms import Tipo_almacenForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import ListView
from appkardex.models import Tipo_almacen

def menu(request):
    return render(request, 'main.html')    

class ListaTipoAlmacen(ListView):
    model = Tipo_almacen
    template_name = 'cruds/lista_tipo_almacen.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListaTipoAlmacen, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        lista_tipo_almacen = Tipo_almacen.objects.all()
        context['lista_tipo_almacen'] = lista_tipo_almacen
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', views.menu),
    url(r'^$', ListaTipoAlmacen.as_view(), name='lista_tipo_almacen')
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL)
```

**main.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'lista_tipo_almacen' %}">Tipo almacen</a></li>
```

**lista_tipo_almacen.html**

```
{% extends "main.html" %}

{% block contenido %}

   <h1>Tipo Almacen</h1>
   <ul>
      {% for lista in lista_tipo_almacen %}
        <li>{{ lista.descripcion }} </li>
      {% endfor %}
   </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Si alguna respuesta ha solucionado tu problema, no olvides votarla y marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score 3):

**ListView** por defecto envía una lista de objetos del modelo que le pases al atributo **model** y en el template lo tomas con el nombre de **object_list** no necesitas utilizar el método **get_context_data** te dejo un ejemplo.

views.py

```
class ListaTipoAlmacen(ListView):
    model = Tipo_almacen
    template_name = 'cruds/lista_tipo_almacen.html'
```

lista_tipo_almacen.html

```
    {% extends "main.html" %}

    {% block contenido %}

     <h1>Tipo Almacen</h1>
     <ul>
        {% for element in object_list %}
          <li>{{ element.descripcion }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
     </ul>

    {% endblock %}
```

Eso es todo!, ahora si deseas cambiar el nombre de la variable **object_list**, en la vista utiliza un atributo más: `context_object_name = 'lista_de_objetos'` y en el template reemplaza **object_list** por `lista_de_objetos`

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a ver, primero, creo que estás haciendo mal uso de las Vistas basadas en Clase, segundo, si no estoy mal tu modelo no se llama lista, sino que se llama `Tipo_almacen`, entonces sería para cada `Tipo_almacen` en `lista_tipo_almacen`.

Inténtalo de esa forma, si falla, me avisas.

Comment: hice como me indicaste pero igual nome carga nada

{% extends "main.html" %}

{% block contenido %}

    <h1>Tipo Almacen</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for Tipo_almacen in lista_tipo_almacen %}
        <li>{{ Tipo_almacen.descripcion }} </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}

Comment: Un concejo mi amigo, todo en inglés y en minúsculas, para evitar problemas.

Comment: Hola @AndresVilca si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto su problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a tí y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm interesante, `ListView` por defecto envía el objeto o la lista en el contexto como `object_list`, veo que usas una función `get_context_data` puedes usar solo `object_list`.

Ejemplo:

```
{% extends "main.html" %}

{% block contenido %}

    <h1>Tipo Almacen</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for lista in object_list %}
        <li>{{ lista.descripcion }} </li>
    {% empty %}
        <p>No hay una lista de almacenes</p>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock contenido %}
```

**views.py:**

```
from appkardex.models import Tipo_almacen
'''
Si tu modelo esta a la par de esta view usa:
from .models import Tipo_almacen
'''

class ListaTipoAlmacen(ListView):
    model = Tipo_almacen
    template_name = 'cruds/lista_tipo_almacen.html'
```

**urls.py:**

Comenta la URL, por que te puede dar problemas por no cerrar con `$`:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  #url(r'^', views.menu),
  url(r'^$', ListaTipoAlmacen.as_view(), name='lista_tipo_almacen')
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco el problema son tus URLs, esta línea:

```
url(r'^', views.menu),
```

Está capturando todo por que has puesto `^` sin nada más, debería tener finalización usando `$`.

Tus URLs podrían quedar así de acuerdo a lo que has brindado en tu código:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', views.menu),
    url(r'^lista/$', ListaTipoAlmacen.as_view(), name='lista_tipo_almacen')
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL)
```

### Actualización

Sobre tu formulario, tienes que pasarlo al context, no basta con importarlo:

```
class ListaTipoAlmacen(ListView):
    model = Tipo_almacen
    template_name = 'cruds/lista_tipo_almacen.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListaTipoAlmacen, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        lista_tipo_almacen = Tipo_almacen.objects.all()
        form = Tipo_almacenForm()
        context['lista_tipo_almacen'] = lista_tipo_almacen
        context['form'] = form
        return context
```

Y renderizarlo en tu template:

```
{% extends "main.html" %}

{% block contenido %}

   <h1>Tipo Almacen</h1>
   <ul>
      {% for lista in lista_tipo_almacen %}
        <li>{{ lista.descripcion }} </li>
      {% endfor %}
   </ul>

   <form method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}
   </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Te recomiendo leer:

- [URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher)
- [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/)