# Error DeleteView

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Hola tengo problema con mi `DeleteView` en Django 1.8, me sale este error:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /eliminar_tipo_almacen/38/appkardex/tipo_almacen_confirm_delete.html

**views.py:**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, UpdateView, DeleteView

class EliminarTipoAlmacen(DeleteView):
    model = Tipo_almacen
    success_url = reverse_lazy('lista_tipo_almacen')



urls.py

url(r'^eliminar_tipo_almacen/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.EliminarTipoAlmacen.as_view(), name='eliminar_tipo_almacen'
```

**lista_tipo_almace.html:**

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Acciones</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    {% for data in lista_tipo_almacen %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ data.descripcion }}</td>
      <td>
       <a href="{% url 'editar_tipo_almacen' data.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file">Editar </span></a>
       <a href="{% url 'eliminar_tipo_almacen' data.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Borrar </span></a>

     </td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**tipo_almacen_confirm_delete.html:**

```
{% extends "main.html" %}

{% block contenido %}
  <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      <p>Quieres eliminar "{{ object }}"</p>
      <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" />
  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Esperando su colaboración

Comment: Si no encuentra tu template debe ser un problema de configuración, edita tu respuesta y muestra la estructura de tus templates asi como la configuración de tus `TEMPLATES` en el `settings.py`

Comment: También te recomiendo que empieces a cerrar tu pregunta anterior si ya encontraste la solución con alguna de las respuestas: [Mostrar datos con ListView con Django 1.8](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2891/100). Si no entiendes algo en SOes, solo pregunta y te ayudaremos

Answer (score 2):

te falta pasar el nombre de la plantilla en tu clase DeleteView

```
template_name = "eliminartipoalmacen.html"
```

creas esa plantilla que sírve para confírmar la eliminación

Answer (score 1):

En los fragmentos de código no dices como se resuelve `lista_tipo_almacen`. Al parecer tu pretendes llamar a una plantilla que se llama así **(aunque no llamas a la plantilla, sino a la vista)**, por lo tanto deberías tener una ruta en tu archivo `urls.py` que resuelva esa llamada.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
url(r'^lista/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='lista_tipo_almacen.html')),
```

En realidad, estás llamando a la función que devuelve la lista tipo almacen, entonces esta es la forma en la que debes llamar a la función:

```
url(r'^lista/$', 'lista', name='lista_tipo_almacen'),
```

O si es una vista basada en clase, sería algo así

```
from .views import Lista:
url(r'^lista/$', Lista.as_view(), name='lista_tipo_almacen'),
```

En todo caso, la función [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy), resuelve una ruta definida en tus patrones de búsqueda, **no llama** a una plantilla directamente.

Comment: Hola @AndresVilca si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto su problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a tí y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.